# MATLAB: F1 help function in Editor refers to a wrong function

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB 2014b.

If I write a line like

```
A = regexp(strcat('some string'),expression);
```

Placing the cursor on the first function (here `regexp`) lets me get the content help of it by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>.

If I now move the cursor to `strcat` I also get the content help of `regexp`. This is just an example; the same problem happens for every function.

In MATLAB 2012b, I get the correct behavior. How can I make MATLAB 2014b act the same way?

Note: If I highlight the function name and press <kbd>F1</kbd>, I'll get the right content help. But this is just a workaround.

Comment: Same issue with Matlab 2014a. I guess the user has no control over this, seems to me a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MATLAB 2012b to test on right now and I'm running 2015a, but I feel it might be an issue with your test case. Try putting the cursor within the brackets that the function is called with. Let me know if it works in 2014b!

regexp help:
[image: http://imgur.com/UtIJ9dg]
strcat help:
[image]

Comment: Anyway if the Cursor is between "r" and "c" in strcat 2014b gives different results compared to 2012b.

Comment: Yeah then I have to agree with @Arpi. This is probably a bug that Mathworks needs to fix.

Comment: @JimPanse On a side note, you would probably have better luck raising the issue if you contacted their support :/